# Use zscan on score

Tags: node.js, redis

According to this https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/896

I have zset , i am saving tokens(element) to corresponding timestamp(score)

Now i want to delete tokens older than particular timestamp using zscan.

```
redis.zscan('my_key', cursor[i], 'MATCH', '*', "COUNT", count, function(err, 
  console.log(err);
  console.log(reply);
});
```

Problem i am having is zscan will return all the values irrespective of timestamp.
This 'MATCH' paramter checks the pattern on elements(token). 
I want to get all the tokens older than some particular timestamp(score).

For example :

```
var startingTime = new Date().getTime();


    redis.zrangebyscore("iflychat_auth_token", 0, startingTime - 43200000 * 2 * 7, function (error, data) {
       // This will return all token older the 7 days.
        });
```

Is there a way to use 'MATCH' on score 
Something like this

```
redis.zscan('my_key', cursor[i], 'MATCH', < timestamp, "COUNT", count, function(err, 
  console.log(err);
  console.log(reply);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`ZSCAN` doesn't have a score range option. The simplest alternative is using Redis' [`ZREMRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore), possibly like so:

```
redis.zremrangebyscore('my_key','-inf', timestamp, function(error,data) { ... });
```

Note: if you need an exclusive range, i.e. < `timestamp`, prepend it with a `(` when sending the value.